# Vertex Multipartition in Hypergraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

An elementary research question concerning a $k$-regular (finite) hypergraph $H$:

I'm looking for a characterization (and the pre-existing name) of the property that the vertices of $H$ split into $k$ classes such that every hyperedge contains a vertex from each class. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"$k$-uniform, $k$-partite"

$k$-uniform means that each edge has $k$ vertices. $k$-partite means there is a vertex partition such that no edge has more than one vertex in each part.